# Tabbar in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am new to android development. Android XML layout has TAB as a UI component. How to use that tab and associate tabs with different views when both TabActivity class and ActivityGroup class are deprecated? Is it possible to use the same UI tab component of the XMl file with the ActionBar ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that TabActivity and ActivityGroup are deprecated, your only option is to use fragments for the tabs' contents.

Download the 4.0 API samples and look at the FragmentTabs activity.